# Spring batch jpa and schema questions

Tags: spring-batch

1. In documentation it says "JPA doesn't have a concept similar to the Hibernate StatelessSession so we have to use other features provided by the JPA specification." - what does this mean? Hibernate is one of the jpa impl so bit confused here

   2. Looking for example where we use jpa infra that we have (entity/crud repo) and we want to use that to read data and write data. Most examples talk about file reading and writing and some about jdbc cursor reader. But since we are using other feature of hibernate like envers we want to use same jpa way that we are using for our online transactions. We are using spring boot/jpa (hibernate) out of the box with oracle and in memory h2 db for dev.
   3. In prod we use oracle, we have user that access to some schemas, how we can inform spring batch to use particular schema to create tables. Right now for some time same application will be use for batch and online so we dont want to use second datasource and different user for batch if possible. Isnt this very basic requirement for all?

Good documentation of spring batch and also liked java/xml config toggle.

We use springboot 2.x with batch.

Comment: Do you know the basics of Spring Batch? You can inject the EntityManger in a ItemReader or ItemWriter. Can you please try to ask more precisely what you need to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. In documentation it says "JPA doesn't have a concept similar to the Hibernate StatelessSession so we have to use other features provided by the JPA specification." - what does this mean?

The direct equivalent of the Hibernate `Session` API in JPA is the `EntityManager`. So this simply means there is no API like `StatelessEntityManager` in JPA, and we need to find a way to achieve the same functionality with JPA APIs only, which is explained in the same section: `After each page is read, the entities become detached and the persistence context is cleared, to allow the entities to be garbage collected once the page is processed.`

> 2. we want to use same jpa way that we are using for our online transactions.

You can use the same DAOs or repositories for both your web app and batch app. For example, the `ItemWriterAdapter` lets you adapt your hibernate/JPA DAO/repository to the item writer interface and use it to persist entities.

> 3. In prod we use oracle, we have user that access to some schemas, how we can inform spring batch to use particular schema to create tables. Right now for some time same application will be use for batch and online so we dont want to use second datasource and different user for batch if possible. Isnt this very basic requirement for all?

You can use the same data source for both your web app and batch app. Then it is up to you to choose the schema for Spring Batch tables. I would recommend using the same schema so that data and meta-data are always in sync (when a Spring Batch transaction fails for example).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. On answer#3, I am trying to find a way to inform spring batch to use particular schema but cant find a way. It just creates in default schema.

Comment: You said you use spring boot, so you can specify the schema in the `spring.datasource.url` property. There is an example in the official docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database.

Comment: Yes. Let me explain again, in our app we have data source that we are using to read data from multiple oracle's tables resides in multiple oracle schemas. And our entities are annotated with schema attribute so we can tell it to create tables in that schema. But for spring batch how we can ask it to create spring batch tables in schemx as we don't have control. Or let's say I can create spring batch tables upfront in schemax but then again how we can inform spring batch to use those tables.

Comment: Spring Batch does not know about schemas, it is configured with a datasource. It is up to you to configure that datasource with schema you want. For example, If you configure your datasource with `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test` and tell spring batch to use that datasource, it will use tables from the `test` schema. Of course, you need either create those tables manually upfront in that schema, or instruct spring boot to do it for you with the `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property.